# Using Jsoup with Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jsoup

I want to call a method in jsoup dynamically. Here is my use case,
I am actually calling multiple select dom methods in jsoup to traverse interior like,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://test.com").get();
String companyName = doc.select("div[class=\"_name\"]").select("span[class="\_name\"]").text();
```

Can I achieve the same dynamically like,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://test.com").get();
String pattern = "select("div[class=\"_name\"]").select("span[class="\_name\"]").text()";
String companyName = doc.pattern;
```

I know we can use reflection to achieve but not sure how to implement this behaviour as pattern string will be dynamic and may have n number of dom selectors.

Let me know if the above dynamism is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, all you have to do is call repetitively the `select()` method on the Document object until you have enumerated all the selectors, and the call the `text()` method.

You can even concat all the selectors in one because `select(div[class=foo]).select(span[class=bar]).text()` is equivalent to `select(div[class=foo] span[class=bar]).text()` which can be simplified to `select(div.foo span.bar).text()`

So maybe you can even discard the whole reflexion thing and create dynamically a correct and direct selector to what you want.

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://test.com").get();
  String companyName = doc.select("div.foo span.bar").text();
```

This is using chaining:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://test.com").get();
List<String> criterias = Arrays.asList("div.foo", "span.bar");
Document tmpDoc = doc;
for (String criteria: criterias) {
    if (tmpDoc != null)
        tmpDoc = tmpDoc.select(criteria);
}
// now you have traversed the whole criterias just get the text
String companyName = tmpDoc.text();
```

Otherwise this is the same using reflection:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://test.com").get();
List<String> criterias = Arrays.asList("div.foo", "span.bar");
Method select = doc.getClass().getMethod("select", String.class);
Document tmpDoc = doc;
for (String criteria: criterias) {
    if (tmpDoc != null)
        tmpDoc = (Document)select.invoke(tmpDoc, new Object[] {criteria});
}
// now you have traversed the whole criterias just get the text
String companyName = tmpDoc.text();
```

Comment: I think you should post the for-each loop code again, but without the reflection. You can chain together all of the selects by just invoking `select` over and over again on `tmpDoc` without using reflection. Reflection is definitely the wrong answer here.

Comment: Yes I know, this is what I stated just above, I posted the code for reflection just so he knows how he could do with it. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice! I agree that it's good to post the reflection code since he specifically asked about reflection, but I'm glad you posted the non-reflection version too so he can see how much better it is without.

Comment: @DaoWen Thank you for your intervention ;-)

Comment: @Alex: Thanks a lot, you saved my day. Just learned that travelling through child elements can also be achieved by a single selector.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to support *n number of dom selectors* then you don't really need reflection because you can just compose them in a single selector string:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://test.com").get();
String pattern = "div[class=\"_name\"] span[class=\"_name\"]"; // Just separate with spaces
String companyName = doc.select(pattern).text();
```